# How to handle NULLs when updating one table from another using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following code, but it updates all the rows in `table_1`, even when the condition is not true (i.e. where `table_1.data_1` is not present at all in `table_2.data_1`). How can I adjust the following update statement so that only the values in `table_1` that match the values in `table_2` are updated?

I am trying to set all the values in `table_1.data_2` to NULL where the `data_1` value is the same in both tables.

```
UPDATE table_1.data_1, table_2.data_1
SET table_1.data_2 = NULL
WHERE table_1.data_1 = table_2.data_1
```

Here is an update to my original post.

```
UPDATE table_1.data_2
SET table_1.data_2 = NULL
WHERE table_1.data_1 IN
(SELECT table_2.data_1 FROM table_2 WHERE table_1.data_1 = table_2.data_1);
```

Comment: [check for NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: ok.. so I will change the above to read: SET table_1.data_2 = NULL ? ... but still not sure about how to handle cases where the data_1 is present in table_1 but not present in table_2 (MySQL sets them all to NULL but I don't want those records to be updated at all...)

Comment: @BenJones with my fist check I given a link. click on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but think something like this would work:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET data_2 = NULL 
  WHERE data_1 IN(SELECT table_1.data_1 
  FROM table_1, table_2 
  WHERE table_1.data_1 = table_2.data_1)
```

I **love** this resource for when I need different ideas on how to approach something:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

**UPDATE:**

```
UPDATE table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 
ON table_1.data_1 = table_2.data_1 AND table_1.data_1 IS NOT NULL
SET table_1.data_2 = NULL;
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'table_1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: How about that second one?  Only other thing I can think of is a temp table right now.